# Notifying users of new messages in android using badges

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i notify users in my app that they have a new message by showing the number of new messages in my chat fragment like a NotificationBadge.

I am using firebase for my app and i have also searched google but non of the examples i saw helped me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: create a flag in firebase if the message was read. if it wasnt read, display a badge.

Comment: @DroiDev i have already done something like that, if message is not seen it makes it bold. but i don't know how to show count

Comment: you have to get the count of how many items are in the DB. for example, if i send YOU a message... or even a group message. that message should consists of a flag set to false. you need to count how many false there are.

Comment: I understand the logic but how to actually show the numbers in my app. sorry i'm kinda new

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about coding for Android apps; however, it may be similar to how you'd do the same for a web app: Assuming your data structure in Firebase is `/userId/messages/new/msgId` you could use the `getChildrenCount()` method and display the result in the notification field.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-guarantees for code examples and documentation of this method.